# Cross reference error when trying to add campaign member

Tags: record-type, campaign, campaign-member

[image]I am trying to manually add a contact as a campaign member to a campaign and am getting a cross-reference error.  When I try this in Classic, I receive the error graphic I am posting in this post.  It appears to definitely have to do with record types since I was messing with the campaign member record types.  I currently have two of them. [image] The profiles appear to have rights to them.

Comment: Please edit your question with some more detail, like the full error message, and whether the campaign member you're trying to add is a Lead or Contact. Also confirm that you're talking about Record Types on Campaign Member, rather than one of the other objects involved. When you say "manually add", are you using the "Add Leads" or "Add Contacts" actions on the Campaign Members related list (Lightning) or the "Add Members - Search" sub-button of "Manage Members" (Classic)? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Record Type for all Campaign Members of a given Campaign is set on the Campaign. The Campaign Member Record Type for the Campaign you're trying to add to is set to one that is inactive, or that is not enabled for your user through Profile or Permission Set.

You can add the Campaign Member Type field to the Campaign page layout or a view to see what Campaign Member Record Type is assigned, and then either grant access or change the Record Type as best suits your needs.

Comment: This is starting to come back to me.  I added the Member Type field to the campaign record.  It shows as blank and there are no choices.  Can you step me through what I need to do to correct the problem?  I would have thought that I could select the member type on the campaign record.  I thought that is what I had done when I set this up a number of months ago.

Comment: Campaigns that were created before you enabled Campaign Member Record Types will be set to the `-Master-` record type, which is no longer available for new records once other Record Types exist. So you need to update the Campaign(s) to have a Campaign Member Type. If you're not seeing options to select a Campaign Member Record Type on the Campaign, then there's not an active one assigned to you, or you're seeing Lightning caching issues.

Comment: I have the record types defined on the campaign member record.  I don't have them on the campaign record.  Should I?  I have the campaign member record type field added to both the campaign and campaign records.  I see that my original record type is now showing - must have been a caching issue.  So...I see there is a valid record type associated with the campaign and campaign member.  I am still getting the error.  Thoughts?

Comment: I don't see any other options in the campaign member type dropdown list although I have two defined on the campaign member record.  I feel like the old campaign member type is displaying but isn't really tied to the record type.

Comment: I updated by problem description to include a picture of the two active record types that I have

Comment: When I create a new campaign, the dropdown for campaign member type is blank.

Comment: Check Campaign Member record type assignment for your profile. Note that if a record type is assigned to a profile, and is decativated and then reactivated, it does **not** recover its profile assignments.

Comment: It works!!!!!  I created a new record type and assigned it to all of the profiles.  I also deleted the old record types & used the utility after deletion to reassign record types.  I think I had multiple issues.  The profile assignment I think came into play.  Thank YOU!!!

Comment: Great! Not to point-pander, but it's best practice to vote an answer up and mark it as correct when that's the case.